# Не сворачивается мобильное меню при переходе по ссылке

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Мобильное меню не сворачивается при переходе по ссылке. Страница пролистывается, но меню не сворачивается. Просьба помочь в решении проблемы.

В класс .main-nav добавляется класс .open, но при выборе пункт меню класс должен пропадать, но он остается и меню остается открытым.

P.s. подобные темы читал, применить у себя не получается.

Ссылка: http://r91432rm.beget.tech

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264) добавьте ваш [mcve] в вопрос, что у вас именно не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На jquery

```
let mainBlock = $('.main-nav');

mainBlock.find('li').on('click', function() {
  mainBlock.removeClass('open');
});
```